# Woocommerce checkout page keeps loading only on HTTPS, but fine on HTTP

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I'm getting this error when on https://www.website.com the page loads but the checkout and order summary wheel keeps spinning none stop, I used google chrome to inspect and I got this

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
checkout.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at update_checkout_action (checkout.min.js:1)
user-avatar-pic.php Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
user-avatar-pic.php Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

now if I removed the s from HTTPs and went to http://www.website.com then the check works fine and this error doesn't get generated

did anyone face this before? I kinda don't know where to start to debug this